# Sort and restructure multidimensional array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have an array like this one:

```
$toSort = array(
    1 => 
        [
            'value' =>  8000,
            'key'   => 1007
        ],
    2 => 
        [
            'value' => 8001,
            'key'   => 1007
        ],
    3 => 
        [
            'value' => 8002,
            'key'   => 1013
        ],
);
```

I want to sort and restructure it like this:

```
$toSort = array(
    1007 => 
        [
            [0] =>  8000,
            [1] =>  8001
        ],
    1013 => 
        [
            [0] => 8002
        ]
);
```

It should work for a random amount of different entries (diffrent keys/values).

Comment: This isn't sorting. Just loop through the input array, and push the value to the element of the output array with the same key.

Comment: Sorting is when you just rearrange the elements of an array according to an ordering criteria, not when you reorganize the structure of the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
//A new array to move the data to.
var $result = array();

//Loop through the original array, and put all the data
//into result with the correct structure.
foreach($toSort as $e) {
    //If this key is not set yet, then create an empty array for it.
    if(!isset($result[$e['key']])) $result[$e['key']] = array()
    //Add the value to the end of the array.
    $result[$e['key']][] = $e['value'];
}

 //Sort the result, based on the key and not the value.
 //If you want it to be based on value, just use sort() instead.
 ksort($result)

 //If you want the sub-arrays sorted as well, loop through the array and sort them.
 foreach($result as $e)
     sort($e);
```

*Disclaimar: I have not tested this code.*

Answer (score 0):

```
$a=array(
    1 => 
        [
            'value' =>  8000,
            'key'   => 1007
        ],
    2 => 
        [
            'value' => 8001,
            'key'   => 1007
        ],
    3 => 
        [
            'value' => 8002,
            'key'   => 1013
        ],
);

$a=call_user_func(function($a){
    $ret=array();

    foreach($a as $v){
    if(array_key_exists($v['key'],$ret)){
        $ret[$v['key']][]=$v['value'];
        } else {
        $ret[$v['key']]=array($v['value']);
        }
        }
        return $ret;
},$a);
var_dump($a);
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to check for the existence of a key before pushing data into it with square brace syntax.

Functional Style: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/U6Fah))

```
var_export(
    array_reduce(
        $toSort,
        function($result, $row) {
            $result[$row['key']][] = $row['value'];
            return $result;
        },
        []
    )
);
```

---

Basic Loop plus array destructuring: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/j0pQC))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($toSort as ['value' => $value, 'key' => $key]) {
    $result[$key][] = $value;
}
var_export($result);
```